# How to pass an object when a button is clicked

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a custom tableview cell which has a button. I need to pass the NSIndexPath object of tablview when the button is clicked. I am able to do is assign a tag to a button, receive the tag using sender..but I want to pass the NSIndexPath object...below is the code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"shortCodeCell";
   IPadTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil)
   {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"KeywordsCell"     owner:nil options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
        {   
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[IPadTableViewCell class]])
            {
                cell = (IPadTableViewCell  *)currentObject;
            }
        }
    }
    // Delete
    [cell.btnDelete addTarget:self action:@selector(onDelete:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    cell.btnDelete.tag=indexPath.row;

    return cell;
}

-(void)onDelete:(id)sender
{   
     UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender;
     NSLog(@"BtnIndexpath to be deleted:%d",btn.tag);
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
     int errorCode = 0;
     kd = [items objectAtIndex:btn.tag];
     BOOL isDeleteKeyword= [ServerAPI deleteKeywordWithId:kd.keywordId :&errorCode];
     dispatch_async (dispatch_get_main_queue (),
                    ^{
                        if (isDeleteKeyword) {
                            [items removeObjectAtIndex:btn.tag];
                            //[tblKeywords deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:btnIndexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];
                            [self.tblKeywords reloadData];
                        }
                        else return;
                    });
    });
}
```

Comment: Your `tag` equals to your `indexPath.row`. What other information do you want from `indexPath`?

Comment: just want to  pass the object indexPath and not the integer value..that is indexPath.row on the below onDelete method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the following in "cellForRowAtIndexPath"

```
cell.tag = indexPath.section; 
cell.btnDelete.tag=indexPath.row;
```

And in "onDelete" you can create indexPath based on tags assigned.

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[sender tag] inSection:[[sender superview] tag]]
```

Comment: thanks man that totally did the trick...one small edification...the row cell gets deleted whith a slide animation..wat i want is once the animation gets completed the tableview cell got to go on top..but here all are happening on the same time

Comment: Do you want to move the cell?

Comment: You can use the following method to move from one indexPath to another. [tableview moveRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[sender tag] inSection:[[sender superview] tag]] toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]]

Answer (score 1):

```
// I assume your UITableView called tableView
// Using this way you don't need to use tag
-(void)onDelete:(id)sender
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[sender superview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
}
```

Comment: Your answer also works. But a little different with OP's question. He/she want to pass that `NSIndexPath`object. But you just create a new one. On the other side OP don't need other info from that `NSIndexPath`. So your answer also works.